# MediaPlayer stops after default click sound is played by Android

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I implemented simple `MediaPlayer` playback mechanism in my app. I'm not sure if that may be the cause of a problem, but everything seemed to work good up to a moment when I upgraded project to newest API (currently 19).
So: playback from file starts normally and suddenly stops when I click a button in my app (which causes the standard 'click sound' to be played). I set `OnCompletionListener` for my MediaPlayer, and it's triggered after click sound, with my MediaPlayer as argument.

```
private void startNewTrack(int which){
        stopTrack();
        try {
            if (mp == null) {
                mp = new MediaPlayer();
                //mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                mp.setOnErrorListener(this);
            }
            MediaMetadataRetriever meta = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            meta.setDataSource(playlist[which].getPath());
            String titleString = meta.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
            if (titleString == null)
                titleString = playlist[which].getName();
            title.setText(titleString);
            album.setText(meta.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM));
            artist.setText(meta.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
            try {
                byte[] pic = meta.getEmbeddedPicture();
                if (pic == null)
                    cover.setImageResource(R.drawable.albumart_mp_unknown);
                else
                    cover.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(pic, 0, pic.length));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                cover.setImageResource(R.drawable.albumart_mp_unknown);
            }
            mp.setDataSource(playlist[which].getPath());
            mp.prepare();
            seek.setMax(mp.getDuration() / 1000);
            mp.start();
            while (playerThread != null)
                Thread.sleep(5);
            playerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    while (mp != null && !isInErrorState) {
                        try {
                            if (!isSeeking && mp.isPlaying()) {
                                final int pos = getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                                MusicPlayback.this.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run(){
                                        seek.setProgress(pos);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            playerThread.start();
            play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            errorMessage();
        }
    }
```

My onCompletion method calls `release()` on `MediaPlayer`. I commented it out temporarily, but it did not change anything.

So the question is: Why my `MediaPlayer` stops when other sound finishes playback? It sometimes even hangs the whole app.

Comment: Are you checking the `MediaPlayer` argument to your `onCompletion` callback to make sure that it's your `MediaPlayer`? If not, that's something you could try.

Comment: Yes. I already do this, and I get my own MediaPlayer when the click sound completes. The sound and music end at the same time.